# Parameter has no default value

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a code below, this code updates the dropdownlist in the gridview. The database is in MS Access
I get the error: "**Parameter @RateCenterName has no default value**."

RateCenterID is the primary key

```
string updateSql = "UPDATE [RateCenters] " + "SET [RateCenterName] = @RateCenterName, [Province]= @Province, [QuantityThreshold] =@QuantityThreshold  " + "WHERE [RateCenterID]=@RateCenterID";

string ratecenterID;

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {                    
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList2");
        TextBox rateCenterName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox1");
        TextBox quantityThreshold = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox2");

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ToString());
        OleDbCommand cmd = null;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(updateSql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RateCenterName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = rateCenterName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Province", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ddl.SelectedValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuantityThreshold", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = quantityThreshold.Text;

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Regards,

Arjun

Answer (score 2):

Your query takes four parameters (`@RateCenterName`, `@Province`, `@QuantityThreshold` and `@RateCenterID`), but you're only passing three.

`@RateCenterID` is missing.

Comment: +1 for you posting the first answer :-)

Comment: yeah Frederic but cmd.Parameters.Add("@RateCenterID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value =???

Comment: Well, you should know what to pass in that parameter since it represents the rate center you're trying to match... I cannot tell you where to get that value from, maybe from user input?

Comment: @Babu _you_ are supposed to fill the _???_ with something meaningful.

Comment: @SalmanA  RateCenterID is the primary key and is not an editable item...so what can I enter in "????"

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi RateCenterID is the primary key and is not an editable item...so what can I enter in "????"

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about the RateCenterID parameter which is being used in where statement.

Hope it helps

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@RateCenterID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ???

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `@RateCenterID` also.

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@RateCenterID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ???

Comment: `rateCenterId`. But that would be a variable you'd of course have to create earlier (around the line of `TextBox rateCenterName` probably).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a value for @RateCenterID.

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@RateCenterID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ???

Comment: That's what you have to know ;-) Maybe you just want to leave out the last part of your query...

Comment: Of course, that would overwrite the 3 columns for *all* rows with same value :)

Comment: @SalmanA yeah I tried it, it happen as you told. What is the perfect solution for my update query error.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared Four Parameters but you have added only Three.

You forgot to add `@RateCenterID` parameter.

Comment: thank you but   cmd.Parameters.Add("@RateCenterID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ???