# How to get rid of "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code,

When the update button in Gridview is clicked , it throws an **error: No value given for one or more required parameters**

but the new updated data can be seen when it is run again, even database is updated.

```
string updateSql = "UPDATE RateCenters SET RateCenterName = @RateCenterName, Province = @Province, QuantityThreshold = @QuantityThreshold" + " WHERE RateCenterID= @RateCenterID";

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {


        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList2"); // assigning the dropdownlist item to 'ddl'

        TextBox rateCenterName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtRateCenterName"); // assigning textbox input item

        TextBox quantityThreshold = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtQuantityThreshold"); // assigning textbox input item

        Label ratecenterid = (Label)row.FindControl("Label1"); // assigning the label value

        //  OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ToString());

        string scon = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\arjun.giridhar\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\BillingApplicationNew\BillingApplicationNew\App_Data\db1.mdb;Persist Security Info=False";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(scon);


        try
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(updateSql, conn);

            cmd.CommandText = updateSql;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RateCenterName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = rateCenterName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Province", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuantityThreshold", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(quantityThreshold.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RateCenterID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ratecenterid.Text);

               conn.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                GridView1.EditIndex = -1; //refreshing
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }         

            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
```

**Below is the stack trace for the above error:**

No value given for one or more required parameters.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace: 
[OleDbException (0x80040e10): No value given for one or more required parameters.]
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr) +1070856
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult) +247
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult) +194
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult) +58
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +167
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +113
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand command, DataSourceOperation operation) +394
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues) +697
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Update(IDictionary keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +95
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleUpdate(GridViewRow row, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean causesValidation) +1226
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +716
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +121
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +125
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +169
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +9
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +176
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563**

Kindly check the code and help me to sort out this task

Regards,
Arjun

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameter has no default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392827/parameter-has-no-default-value)

Comment: As the error sounds tbh : one or more values are not being passed through.  A tiny bit of debugging will help out here to find the culprit.  However, my money is on the dropdown box losing its entries due to the PageLoad rebinding the entries...

Comment: @AliIssa tried debugging, coudln't solve this.

Answer (score 2):

From [OleDbCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx):

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
> ```

So try using unnamed parameters instead (see the documentation for a full example).

Comment: @Ravia: It's not really clear what the OP means by that - I read that as an unclear way of saying "But I'm specifying all the parameters".

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I have edited that but the error is still the same!

Comment: @ArjunBabu: Could you clarify what you meant by "but the fields are updated in the update event" - do you mean  they *are* being changed in the database? Could you post the *full* exception stack trace and message, along with the edited code?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Fields are updated and the new updated data are seen during the second run but when the update button is clicked it throws this error "No Value given for one or more required parameter"

Comment: @ArjunBabu What do you have in your Update button event?

Comment: @ArjunBabu: What do you mean by "during the second run"? It sounds like you've got a *lot* more context you should be telling us. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet: Running the program again.

Comment: @Ravia: I don't have anything in Update button event

Comment: @ArjunBabu: And the full stack trace?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I have added the stack trace in the question as well

Comment: @ArjunBabu, I believe, you are sending a null value for a column which is suppose to consume not null values.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the below link, under Remarks it says "A common way to use these collections is to HTML-encode the values supplied by the user before they are stored in the data source."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx